# Spring mvc Command object breaking Encoding

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller, encoding

I have a spring mvc hibernate setup that I did.

But.. when I load a `Command` object in one of my forms for "update" - the `Command` object have some @validations -, if I update the fields in latin chars there are no problems, but if I input some text in bulgarian/russian - when I try to submit the changes (the validation error will be thrown on purpose just for the test), but the char encoding is lost and they look like from the monkey alphabet.

What is breaking my encoding? I set the jsp encoding to be "UTF-8" but still not working.

[image: image 1 - still no problem]

And now after I click SUBMIT:

[image: after the submit]

This is the page code:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
    
<!DOCTYPE >
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
<title>User Information 1.0.1</title>
<link href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
                 rel="stylesheet">
</head>
 <body>
 <div class="container">
 <h3>User Info:</h3>
  <form:form method="post" commandName="userinfo">
   
   <fieldset class="form-group">
    <form:label class="form-check-label" path="name">Name</form:label>
    <form:input class="form-control" path="name" type="text" required="required"></form:input>
    <form:errors path="name" cssClass="text-warning"></form:errors>
   </fieldset>
   
   <fieldset class="form-group">
    <form:label class="form-check-label" path="pin">PIN</form:label>
    <form:input class="form-control" path="pin" type="text" required="required"></form:input>
    <form:errors path="pin" cssClass="text-warning"></form:errors>
   </fieldset>
   
   <fieldset class="form-group">
    <form:label class="form-check-label" path="email">Email</form:label>
    <form:input class="form-control" path="email" type="text" required="required"></form:input>
    <form:errors path="email" cssClass="text-warning"></form:errors>
   </fieldset>
   
   <fieldset class="form-group">
    <form:label class="form-check-label" path="emailType">Email Type</form:label>
    <form:input class="form-control" path="emailType" type="text" required="required"></form:input>
    <form:errors path="emailType" cssClass="text-warning"></form:errors>
   </fieldset>
   
   
   <fieldset class="form-group">
    <form:label class="form-check-label" path="address">Address</form:label>
    <form:input class="form-control" path="address" type="text" required="required"></form:input>
    <form:errors path="address" cssClass="text-warning"></form:errors>
   </fieldset>
   
   <fieldset class="form-group">
    <form:label class="form-check-label" path="addressType">Address Type</form:label>
    <form:input class="form-control" path="addressType" type="text" required="required"></form:input>
    <form:errors path="addressType" cssClass="text-warning"></form:errors>
   </fieldset>
   
   <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit" ></input>
  </form:form>
 </div>
 <script src="webjars/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And yes.. I found the mistake on the first line, but its not fixing it.